# How to translate interactive graphics from Mathematica to standard HTML+SVG?

Tags: graphics, export, html, svg-format

I have a simple interactive plot in *Mathematica*, with controls for various parameters. The point of the plot is simply that users can explore how the plot changes as the parameters change by manipulating controls.  IOW, this is `Dynamic`-101 stuff (which is my level at the moment).

I would like to convert this to (non-proprietary) HTML + SVG (+ CSS, JavaScript, etc., as needed).

Is there a straightforward path for doing this? I know that one can export *Mathematica* graphics to SVG, but I'm not sure how one would export the dynamic behavior described above.

(BTW, I've looked for ways to do this starting from JavaScript to begin with, but I have found that JavaScript support for plotting is rather primitive. JavaScript graphics seem to be mostly about Illustrator-type stuff, and more recently, "data visualization". In comparison, there's almost nothing in the JavaScript graphics universe for plotting functions, the way `Plot` et al. do.)

Comment: Did you take a look at http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/ ?

Comment: @Ajasja: That's precisely one of the options I was trying to exclude with the "non-propietary" qualifier...

Comment: There's no built-in functionality for export of dynamic `SVG + JS` or `HTML5`. The best high-level way to create `HTML + JS` in my opinion is [Processing/JS](http://processing.org/) - in particular, look at the reference for `processing.js` which exports interactive pages *without* requiring `Java` applets. Their older web export is `Java` applet based, but is very capable. [Here](http://www.gwoptics.org/processing/michelson01/) is an example of an added library for plotting, combined with interactivity.

Comment: There's also [geogebra](http://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Tutorial:Creating_HTML5_documents_with_GeoGebraWeb), if you're especially interested in math visualization.

Comment: [webMathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/) might be the most straightforward for this, though not ideal.

Comment: When you create interactive demonstrations in Mathematica, computations are typically done live.  For any non-trivial problem you won't have access to all the function needed for this in JavaScript, so a more practical solution would be to pre-compute everything for a set of values of a manipulated parameter and export the results (say, as images).  If we could find some existing browser based solution which allows dynamically seeking anywhere in an animation (e.g. animated GIF), we could use that to play back the results. Perhaps yo can try to find something like this.

Comment: @Szabolcs I could try to post something like what you're describing later today, based on a simple JS movie player that I wrote myself some time ago.

Comment: @Szabolcs Of course that's getting to be much more a Javascript than a *Mathematica* problem.

Comment: @Jens I'm interested, I always wanted to have this functionality.  Manipulate/Animation can be exported to Flash (SWF) but it runs automatically, it won't let me drag the slider.  All I'd like is to be able to drag a slider when there's a single one.

Comment: See also my related question that focuses on D3 viz: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5416/strategies-for-interfacing-to-web-visualization-libraries-like-stanfords-data-d

Comment: @kjo just for interest, could you clarify in your question why only non-proprietary solutions are acceptable to you? When talking about Mathematica, these issues often arise, and I'm interested in the thinking behind the question...

Comment: @cormullion: I can't come up with a quick and non-controversial answer to your question...  :)

Comment: @kjo No problem - just puzzled...:) I understand why some people prefer open source and non-proprietary solutions, just can't see why you're happy with Mathematica but not with CDF. (Well, CDF isn't perfect, but it's an obvious solution.)

Comment: @Jens Did you manage to get it working with your JS movie player?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes. I just have to figure out how to get the `JavaScript` code posted without line breaks getting messed up. I had it inside *Mathematica* strings, and that doesn't upload correctly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Animations as interactive visualizations

The simplest form of interactive graphics is an **animation** in which the play head can be moved by the user. That doesn't sound very interactive, but in terms of functionality the play head is nothing but a type of `Slider`.

With this simple interpretation of interactivity, any movie format supported by `Export` would be a way to create a standalone "interactive" visualization.

The starting point for this approach would be to generate a list of graphics that will form the frames of the animation:

```
frames = Table[
   Plot[Sin[φ x]/(φ x), {x, -1, 1}, Background -> White, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-.5, 1}}], {φ, Pi,10 Pi, Pi/2}];
```

I've added a `Background` to the plot because it will be needed to make the `SVG` version of the movie come out properly below.

#### Frame based animations with SVG

But the other part of your question is specifically asking about `SVG` and `HTML` format. In `SVG`, you can create animations by moving elements around using `JavaScript`. But that's not something you can easily automate in exporting a *Mathematica* dynamic object - it would require case-by-case fine tuning.

So instead, I pursued a totally different way to combine the first point (the movie paradigm) with `SVG`: export an animation in which *each frame* is a static `SVG` vector graphic. Then the interactive element is again realized by the mere presence of the play head as a slider.

To make this a *little more* interesting than a typical movie player, I also added the ability to export a sequence of `N` graphics but create a larger number `M > N` of frames from them in the animation. This is achieved by allowing an *indexed list* to specify the movie frames, so the `M` frames can walk through the `N` graphics in any order with arbitrary repetitions during playback.

#### The Javascript movie player

The whole thing is based on a `JavaScript` movie player I had written earlier, so you also get the ability to encode your frames as standard `PNG` bitmaps instead of `SVG`.

**The special thing about the player is that it's a single standalone `HTML` file**. All movie frames are *embedded* in the `HTML` using `base64` encoding, so the animation remains just as portable as a normal movie, `GIF` etc.

But the `SVG` playback ability is what makes this most relevant to your question. Since `SVG` takes more resources to store and interpret during the display, one can notice that the player is somewhat slower to start up when you choose `SVG` format instead of the default `PNG` format.

However, the nice thing is that `SVG` animations can be enlarged without loss of quality, *even while the movie is running*.

I'm putting this out there for experimentation, and `SVG` may not turn out to be the best choice for your application. But then you can still go with `PNG` and get a smooth frame animation with full slider control.

The `JavaScript` player has some additional features in addition to a draggable play head. Since it's frame-based, you can **interactively** change the frame delay, press `a` to display all frames side-by-side, and change the looping behavior.

```
htmlTemplate = 
    Import["http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/jensPlayer/jensPlayerTemplate.js", "Text"];
jensPlayer[name_?StringQ, a_?ListQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {delay = 50, dataType = "img", htmlString, htmlBody,
   scaledFrames, n, i, movieFrames, dimensions, frameStartTag, 
   frameEndTag, exportFormat, imgSizeRule, 
   loopOptions = {"Loop" -> "rightLoopButton", 
     "None" -> "noLoopButton", "Palindrome" -> "palindromeButton"},
   toolHeight = 25},
  n = Range[Length[a]];
  imgSizeRule = FilterRules[{opts}, ImageSize];
  If[imgSizeRule == {}, imgSizeRule = (ImageSize -> Automatic)];
  scaledFrames = Map[Show[#, imgSizeRule] &, a];
  dimensions = ImageDimensions[Rasterize[scaledFrames[[1]]]];
  With[{del = ("Delay" /. {opts})}, If[NumericQ[del], delay = del]];
  With[{ind = ("Indices" /. {opts})}, 
   If[ListQ[ind], i = ind - 1, i = n - 1]];
  Which[("SVG" /. {opts}) === True, 
   dataType = "object", ("SVGZ" /. {opts}) === True, 
   dataType = "embed"];
  If[dataType == "embed",
   frameStartTag = "<embed src=\"";
   frameEndTag = 
    "\" width=\"" <> ToString[dimensions[[1]]] <> "\"height=\"" <> 
     ToString[dimensions[[2]]] <> "\">";
   htmlString = "";
   movieFrames =
    Table[
     With[{svgName = 
        name <> ToString[
          PaddedForm[i, Total@DigitCount[Length[scaledFrames]], 
           NumberPadding -> {"0", " "}]] <> ".svgz"},
      Export[svgName, scaledFrames[[i]], "SVGZ"]; 
      frameStartTag <> svgName <> frameEndTag], {i, 
      Length[scaledFrames]}];
   htmlString = StringJoin[movieFrames],
   If[dataType == "img",
    frameStartTag = "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,";
    frameEndTag = "\">";
    movieFrames = Apply[If[("Parallel" /. {opts}) === False,
       Map, ParallelMap], {ExportString[#, "PNG"] &, scaledFrames}],
    frameStartTag = "<object data=\"data:image/svg+xml;base64,";
    frameEndTag = "\" type=\"image/svg+xml\"></object>";
    movieFrames = Apply[If[("Parallel" /. {opts}) === False,
       Map, ParallelMap], {ExportString[#, "SVG"] &, scaledFrames}]
    ];
   htmlString = 
    StringJoin@
     If[("Parallel" /. {opts}) === False, 
      Map[(StringJoin[frameStartTag, 
          StringReplace[ExportString[#, "Base64"], "\n" -> ""], 
          frameEndTag]) &, movieFrames],
      DistributeDefinitions[frameStartTag]; 
      DistributeDefinitions[frameEndTag]; 
      ParallelMap[(StringJoin[frameStartTag, 
          StringReplace[ExportString[#, "Base64"], "\n" -> ""], 
          frameEndTag]) &, movieFrames]
      ]
   ];
  htmlBody = 
   StringReplace[
     htmlTemplate, {"**DATE**" -> DateString[], 
      "**DATATYPE**" -> dataType, 
      "**WIDTH**" -> ToString[dimensions[[1]]], 
      "**HEIGHT**" -> ToString[dimensions[[2]]], 
      "**TOOLHEIGHT**" -> ToString[toolHeight], 
      "**DELAY**" -> ToString[delay], 
      "**COMBINEDWIDTH**" ->  ToString[Length[a]*dimensions[[1]]], 
      "**USERNAME**" -> $UserName, 
      "**LOOPCONTROL**" -> 
       With[{loopOption = ("Looping" /. {opts}) /. loopOptions}, 
        If[MemberQ[loopOptions[[All, 2]], loopOption], loopOption, 
         "None" /. loopOptions]], 
      "**INDICES**" -> StringJoin@Riffle[Map[ToString, i], ","], 
      "**AUTOPLAY**" -> 
       If[("AutoPlay" /. {opts}) === True, "true", "false"], 
      "**TITLE**" -> name}] <> htmlString <> "</div></body></html>";
  Export[name, htmlBody, "TEXT"];
  ]
```

#### Examples

With this function you can now export the frames created earlier:

```
jensPlayer["sombrero.html", frames]

SystemOpen["sombrero.html"]

jensPlayer["sombreroIndexed.html", frames, "Delay" -> 60, 
 "AutoPlay" -> True, "Looping" -> "Palindrome", "Parallel" -> True, 
 "Indices" -> {19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 15, 17, 18, 19, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15,
    14, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 
   9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19}]

SystemOpen["sombreroIndexed.html"]

jensPlayer["sombreroSVG.html", frames, "SVG" -> True]

SystemOpen["sombreroSVG.html"]
```

Each of the export commands illustrates a different export format.

#### Options

By default, the images in list images are displayed sequentially with a constant time delay, in a single playback run. If the option `"Indices"` is specified, frames are played back in the order determined by that option, see below.

Options (except for ImageSize, all options are strings requiring quotation marks):

- `ImageSize`

  - number of pixels in the horizontal direction. If unspecified, will be determined by size of the graphics in images.
- `"Looping"`

  - `"None"` (default),
  - `"Loop"`
  - `"Palindrome"`
- `"Delay"`

  - number of milliseconds between frames (default `50`)
- `"Indices"`

  - `{i1, i2,... iN}`, a list of (not necessarily different) integers between `1` and `Length[images]`. The
    number of frames in the movie is `N`. `in` (`n = 1,...N`) is the index in list `a` of the image to be displayed as frame `n`.
- `"AutoPlay"`

  - `True`
  - `False` (default)
  - sets whether the movie should start playing as soon as loaded.
- `"Parallel"`

  - `True` (default)
  - `False`
  - switches between parallel/sequential image conversion. `Parallel` speeds up the export if more than one *Mathematica* Kernel is available.
- `"SVG"`

  - `True`
  - `False` (default)
  - switches between `SVG` or `PNG` format for the frame export. `SVG` format is provided on an experimental basis because browser support is evolving slowly. It is a resolution-independent graphics format that can be resized seamlessly in Firefox. `SVG` requires larger startup time, so it should not be used for large movies. With `SVG` you should also specify an explicit background for the frames, e.g. by doing `images=Map[Show[#,Background->White]&,originalImages]`. Although `SVG` movies yield much larger `HTML` files, `gzip` compression can make file sizes comparable to those of `PNG` movies (or even smaller). Since web servers increasingly are configured to transmit `HTML` files using on-the-fly compression, `SVG` does not necessarily increase download times.

#### Additional notes

Because the `JavaScript` file is too unwieldy for this post, I put it on my web site and use `Import` in the `jensPlayer` function to load it. I would suggest that you download the file

> http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/jensPlayer/jensPlayerTemplate.js

and copy and paste it as a string into the `htmlTemplate =` assignment. Then you can use the function offline.

Also, I had tried `SVGZ` instead of `SVG`, and the function allows that as an option. However, this compressed `SVG` format doesn't play back so well apparently. Maybe the decompression is causing problems - I haven't had time to debug that yet. So I'd recommend you not use `SVGZ` at the moment, even though you may have seen it in the code above.

**Illustrated example**

To show what the movie should look like, here is a sequence of images that represent an electric field distribution for a range of separations `d` between two charged objects. The parameter `d` is then controlled with the movie slider:

```
field[a_, d_, x_, y_] = 
  D[Log[((x - d)^2 + y^2)/((x - a)^2 + y^2)], {{x, y}}];
images = With[{r = 1.}, Table[
    Show[
     StreamPlot[field[1/d, d, x, y], {x, -2, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
      FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
      StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
      PlotLabel -> Row[{"d = ", PaddedForm[N@d, {4, 2}]}]], 
     Graphics[{Thickness[.009], White, Circle[{0, 0}, r], 
       PointSize[.03], Point[{d, 0}]}], Background -> GrayLevel[.2], 
     LabelStyle -> White, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Lighter@Gray, Thickness[.005]], 
     ImageMargins -> 5],
    {d, 1.5 r, 4 r, r/4}]];

jensPlayer["imageChargesSVG.html", images, "SVG" -> True, 
 "Parallel" -> False]
```

> [image: example movie]

The movie is a screen recording of the `JavaScript` movie player in Google Chrome. The controls at the bottom fade in and out. The left-most control switches between single run, back-and-forth (palindromic) playback and looping. I show how to stop the movie by pressing the red button, and then drag the slider to get to a particular frame. After restarting and stopping agin, I click on the frame counter to get a dialog that allows interactive adjustment of the frame delay. After changing the delay to `250` milliseconds, the playback is slower.

There are several other keyboard shortcuts that are explained if you click the question mark at the bottom right. In particular, you can use arrow keys to move from frame to frame while the movie is stopped.

Answer (score 9):

As [Jens points out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18257/how-to-translate-interactive-graphics-from-mathematica-to-standard-htmlsvg/18382#18382), we can certainly generate a *single slider* version of Manipulate in a web page. Evidently, [someone else has recently taken up this challenge](https://compdatanotes.com/blog/manipulate1s/).

The correct, general answer is still *no*, there is no straightforward (built-in) way to convert Mathematica's dynamic objects to non-proprietary HTML+SVG/JS.  To see why, consider how you might try to represent the following very simple example in HMTL/SVG:

```
Manipulate[With[{pts = {#, Sin[a*#]} & /@ (x /.
  Quiet[Solve[Sin[a*x] == b*AiryAi[-x] && 0 < x < 10, x],
    {Solve::nint, Solve::ratnz}])},
  Plot[{Sin[a*x], b*AiryAi[-x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> 
   {PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}]],
  {{a, 1}, 1, 10}, {{b, 2}, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

---

Of course, the point is that most interesting dynamic illustrations in Mathematica will make use of Mathematica's extensive library of mathematical functionality - functionality not generally available in GeoGebra, D3, or javascript libraries such as processing.js or numeric.js.  This exact point was made in the comments, but without example.

It is not my point to demean those other tools at all - simply to point out that their emphasis is different.  If your objective to create broadly accessible (i.e., without plugins) illustrations based on *simple* mathematics, then perhaps you should focus on those types of tools.  If you need to create illustrations that require more advanced (mathematical) functionality, then it will be hard to beat Mathematica.  Clearly, Wolfram Research is aware of the need to disseminate material created with Mathematica and have released web Mathematica and CDF for exactly this purpose.

The particular example that I gave is *very* easy in Mathematica precisely because it has an excellent library of special functions and well integrated tools for solving equations involving those functions.  (Any number of other examples could be given.)  Implementing this example in javascript would be challenging, since you'd have to implement the fundamentals yourself.

It's amusing that some anonymous user chose to downvote this answer without accepting that challenge.

Comment: "Whatever your approach, you'd certainly need a good library of special functions and tools to solve equations involving these over entire intervals"  Well, a point to such a library was one of the types of answers I was hoping for...  Thanks for the nice example, BTW!

Comment: I don't know much about SVG yet, but my impressions about it so far are consistent with your comments.  Namely, SVG provides the graphics primitives, but there do not seem be any decent libraries (in JavaScript or anything else) to support higher-level programming of SVG-based plots.

Comment: @kjo, The D3 API developed at Stanford by Heer and others, has been used extensively by NYTimes among others for interactive viz (see the link in my comment above for examples)

Comment: I think the question is valid because `CDF` isn't viable in all scenarios where `HTML + SVG` is available. So I still want to post an alternative answer - but I didn't downvote yours because it's certainly a correct descriptin of the difficulties. And a constructive answer unfortunately takes a little longer...

Comment: @Jens Clearly, the question is valid - I don't mean to imply otherwise. It's just that the short answer is *no*, there is no straightforward (built-in) way to convert Mathematica's dynamic objects to non-proprietary HTML+SVG/JS. The longer answer illustrates why. I wouldn't think you're the down-voter, by the way!

Comment: Even if CDF weren't a proprietary technology belonging to WRI (in contrast, e.g., to HTML + SVG), the fact that, AFAIK, it requires downloading and installing a separate viewer is a deal-breaker for the type of use cases I'm interested in at the moment. I confess that I don't know much about webMathematica, except that using it requires giving WRI more money... (I gave up trying to get the straight scoop on webMathematica after following one-too-many hyperlink to a sales-hype-filled page.)

Answer (score 9):

For the benefit of those who come across this old question, I have recently written a small open-source library called [MathCell](https://github.com/paulmasson/mathcell) that replicates the behavior of Mathematica's `Manipulate` using pure JavaScript. Documentation is available [here](https://paulmasson.github.io/mathcell/docs/).

The library is not for converting Mathematica code, but is meant as a replacement for people who want to embed interactive math in a web page. There is a template in the documentation to set up an area on the page containing HTML elements (range sliders, number inputs, checkboxes) for parameter input, with an output below them that can be an SVG plot, a 3D graphic using Three.js or simple text as desired.

And since JavaScript is limited in its available functions, I also started a library simply called [Math](https://github.com/paulmasson/math) to provide special functions and basic numerical operations, such as root finding, quadrature, integration of differential equations and eigensystems of real symmetric matrices.

Comment: Could you give a short description of how it works? I.e. what it the input to MathCell? I assume the output is the Javascript?  Do you mean you convert Manipulate code to Javascript?

Comment: @Nasser description updated

Comment: The [JSForm](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library/blob/master/symja_android_library/doc/functions/JSForm.md) function creates JavaScript output which can be used with the Math, MathCell and JSXGraph libraries.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possibilities, I can suggest from my side

Either use [WLJS Frontend](https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/), that supports exporting notebooks to an HTML or React component, however it is still very raw, has no direct compatibility with Mathematica and the second option might suit better.

Second option - export your graphs to `ExpressionJSON` and feed it to a [Javascript Wolfram Language runtime](https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/docs/interpreter/intro). The graphics library is quite limited, but for the regular plots it works well.

Both of those options provides dynamics, sliders and etc, however in a different form. It might take some time to get used to this frameworks. Not event mentioning a lot of bugs and so on... ;)

[image]