# Alternatives to Mathematica that are not computer algebra systems

Tags: image-processing, physics, natural-language

Are there alternatives to *Mathematica* that are not computer algebra systems?

I know there have been questions on this, but I am focusing on oprn source projects and instead of focusing on computer algebra systems, I am interested in scientific functions, image processing, language processing, and more. I am looking for an easy to understand module or language based on the "knowledge based programming" paradigm.

Comment: Kind of like going to an organic food forum and asking for junk food suggestions, no? Probably better served asking on some open-source/python fora...

Comment: I'd be impressed if you found one, because knowledge bases are really hard and boring to construct. I imagine only people who are paid to do it would do it.

Comment: PARI-GP is free and very fast for numerical computing, and handy for number theory: http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: Should I ask this question on stack overflow?

Comment: @ciao according to uour logic, shouldn't http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28162/alternatives-to-mathematica be closed?

Comment: @TanMath You could try asking on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/  Instead of simply asking "alternative to Mathematica, but not CAS", describe in more detail what tasks you would solve with such a system, and what current features of Mathematica you would like to have in the other system.  I would not ask on StackOverflow, these sorts of questions get closed there.

Comment: Why closed?  In my personal opinion, the question you linked is pretty borderline ... when you also add "not CAS", I get the impression that this is really asking "what systems are there for solving these and these kinds of tasks".  The focus is not Mathematica but the use cases of the system.  Thus it is not a question about Mathematica (even if bringing up a comparison with certain Mathematica features might help in clarifying the question).