# Is there a way to communicate wtih Modelica other than SystemModeler?

Tags: system-modeler

[This](http://matlink.org/) is a full-featured, free (freedom and beer) interconnect between Mathematica and Matlab. Conversely, [this](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/) is Wolfram's own commercial solution for connecting Modelica models to Mathematica. Is there a free alternative? None of my searches have found one. I'd be more than happy with something that imports model governing equations.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28162)

Comment: Debatable. If I wanted to get off of Mathematica I would have done so. Perhaps there is something out there with a better ode solver, or something, but I'm not at the point yet where I can even collect any evidence.

Comment: I'm just saying that a question like yours has been asked before, except it was about *Mathematica* and not SystemModeler. As you can see from that other question, I'm not sure about the topicality of your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood you. I would still respectfully disagree. I'm not seeking a replacement to any program, just a technique to communicate with modelica. I will update the title to reflect this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

I'll preface with the fact that I'm a developer for SystemModeler.

There are a number of other [Modelica tools](https://modelica.org/tools) on the market, some of them free. They all have their various strength and weaknesses.

The only one that has a connection to Mathematica is SystemModeler, as far as I'm aware.

You could probably build your own link between Mathematica and one of the other tools, but it would be something you would have to do from scratch, utilizing any APIs the tool of your choice happens to have available.

Edit: Starting with Mathematica 11.3, [some system modeling functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SystemModelingOverview.html) comes built-in, without needing to buy SystemModeler. SystemModeler remains as a graphical tool for modeling and simulation.

Comment: "You could probably build your own link between Mathematica and one of the other tools" ... which would be a huge amount of work. That is why SystemModeler costs money and why MATLink development has (unfortunately) essentially halted.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially it. Building a (good) such link is a lot of work, both up front, and continuously keeping up to date with API changes on both sides.

Comment: [Could you please give some guidance to those of us who have zero knowledge about SystemModeler, and are wondering what we can do with all these new functions in 11.3?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167555/12)

Comment: Basically, it looks like a numerical diff eq solver to me.  But I am sure that from a practical perspective it is much more than that.  I am hoping for an explanation that demonstrates this.