# How to put my Matematica manipulation into html code?

Tags: html

I have a rather simple question to which I can't find answer on web : suppose I have written a Manipulation in Mathematica, a beautiful .nb file that generates some presentation. Let us say, I draw an ellipse.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{a Sin[(t)], b Cos[(t)]}, {t, 0, 20 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
 {{a, 1}, 0, 1}, {{b, 1}, 0, 1}]
```

I would like to put a resulting manipulation on my web site.
Is it possible, and if yes, what are y options ?

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/deploying-cdf/web-delivery-cloud.html

Comment: If you only want to vary a single parameter, I'd suggest exporting as a movie instead. Then it can be embedded without the CDF plugin, and is therefore more portable. The movie playhead then serves as the slider to control the parameter. If you want a high quality animation, you may be interested in this question: [How to translate interactive graphics from Mathematica to standard HTML+SVG?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18257/245)

Comment: CDF plugin is dying so you could use `CloudDeploy`, it will eat your credits though.

Answer (score 1):

The days of plugin are long gone. In a video of WRI 2016 conference, there was talk that in 11.2 there will new features for CDF, including what is called `portable CDF` and `web applets/microsites` and new `CDF export wizard`.  See video by Andre Kuzniarek here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjG0gTSUsPY&list=PLxn-kpJHbPx0xBVkORRdoQbahhhE8Sn04&index=69

Some of the highlights of talk: (coming in future version of Mathematica)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]